# SBT: Make "publish" and "package" depend on "test"

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to SBT and trying to convert my gradle project to SBT (1.0.4).
I want to trigger "test" task for both "publish" and "package" automatically. In my settings I have the following:

```
Keys.`package` in Compile := (Keys.`package` in Compile).dependsOn(test in Test).value,
```

When I run `./sbt package` it works as expected (tests are started before the "package" phase). But when I run `./sbt publish` the `test` task is ignored. Since `publish` depends on `package`, I expect `test` being executed in both cases. What am I missing?